# how to solve 'list' object has no attribute 'apply'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset-adu_tracts(32561,) like that:

```
 [[2, 7, 15, 28, 39, 46, 59, 69, 72, 76, 78, 83, 90, 95],
 [3, 11, 15, 28, 39, 48, 56, 68, 72, 76, 77, 83, 89, 95],
 [2, 9, 18, 27, 37, 44, 57, 69, 72, 76, 77, 83, 90, 95], ...]
```

I want to make a statistic of it:

```
ou_sta = adu_tracts.apply(pd.value_counts)
```

However, there is no apply attribute in list, I used `np.matrix(adu_tracts)`  `np.array(adu_tracts)`, it still show these object have no apply attribute, how to solve it?

Comment: `apply` is a DataFrame or Series method and you tagged this with `pandas` so do you perhaps mean to have a DataFrame of those values?

Comment: How about `pd.DataFrame(adu_tracts).apply(pd.value_counts())`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for:

```
d =  [[2, 7, 15, 28, 39, 46, 59, 69, 72, 76, 78, 83, 90, 95],
 [3, 11, 15, 28, 39, 48, 56, 68, 72, 76, 77, 83, 89, 95],
 [2, 9, 18, 27, 37, 44, 57, 69, 72, 76, 77, 83, 90, 95]]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
print(df.apply(pd.value_counts))

      0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13
2   2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
3   1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
7   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
9   NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
15  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
18  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
27  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
28  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
37  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
39  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
44  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
46  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
48  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
56  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
57  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
59  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
68  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
69  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
72  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
76  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
77  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
78  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN  NaN  NaN
83  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN
89  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  1.0  NaN
90  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  2.0  NaN
95  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  3.0
```

Comment: Thanks again, that's what I want but is there some method can only show the value, didn't show NaN?

Comment: What value do you want instead of NaN?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, actually I want to make statistic plot for those 13 column, for example, in the 1st pic, it shows there are 2 value-2, 1value-1. so there will be 13 pics in the end